# Inject IF condition Jenkinsfile

Tags: if-statement, jenkins, kubernetes, jenkins-pipeline

Trying to create a Jenkins job to delete Kubernetes objects.

The shell script works fine doing something like

```
kubectl delete service \$(kubectl get service | grep ${rescName} | awk \'{print \$1}\')"
```

The issue I have is that running it a second time fails with the error

```
error: resource(s) were provided, but no name, label selector, or --all flag specified
```

How can an if statement be passed in so that it first checks if the service exists before running the `kubectl delete service` command and prints out a message if it doesn't exist instead of erroring and failing.

Comment: I would move all the logic of execution in the jenkins-shared library functions and put in the jenkinsfile only the call for a specific type of the deployment. This means that I can change/improve/bugfix the logic later without altering 100 jenkinsfiles.  https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/

Answer (score 0):

to use IF loop it's better to use sh step in pipeline:

```
stage ('some text here') {
  steps {
    sh """
      if ... 
      do 
      else
      done
    """
  }
}
```

Comment: Makes sense.

What I'm trying to figure out if how to check if the service already exists first

Comment: You will need to use something like
`kubectl get services` 
and filter results

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll have a crack at it.